# Camel Context not getting initialized for Spring Boot CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, apache-camel, spring-batch

I am trying to run a cql query using camel in a spring boot application (using spring batch).
When I try running a similar code in a Spring Boot Web App, it runs fine, but when I try to run the same code using a CommandLineRunner, it doesn't.

I compared the startup logs of both the application.
The problem seems to be in the **initialization of the Camel Context**. It gets initialized fine in the Web Project (which uses a @RestController), but doesn't seem to get initialized in the CommandLineRunner one.

**The web App Log:**

```
2020-01-22T10:48:25.214Z INFO  SystemapiCassandraAccountByLpidhashApplication [{}]: Starting SystemapiCassandraAccountByLpidhashApplication on WV-MN14GLAE62KT with PID 15092 (C:\Repositories\Mule2SB\a0011-account-by-lpidhash\target\classes started by c052699 in C:\Repositories\Mule2SB\a0011-account-by-lpidhash)
2020-01-22T10:48:25.245Z INFO  SystemapiCassandraAccountByLpidhashApplication [{}]: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-22T10:48:27.646Z INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [{}]: Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$18670c03] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-22T10:48:28.137Z INFO  TomcatWebServer [{}]: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9084 (http)
2020-01-22T10:48:28.168Z INFO  Http11NioProtocol [{}]: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9084"]
2020-01-22T10:48:28.187Z INFO  StandardService [{}]: Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-01-22T10:48:28.188Z INFO  StandardEngine  [{}]: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2020-01-22T10:48:28.552Z INFO  [/system-api/accountbylpidhash] [{}]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-01-22T10:48:28.552Z INFO  ContextLoader   [{}]: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3236 ms
2020-01-22T10:48:29.204Z INFO  DefaultTypeConverter [{}]: Type converters loaded (core: 195, classpath: 11)
2020-01-22T10:48:29.622Z INFO  GuavaCompatibility [{}]: Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
2020-01-22T10:48:29.650Z INFO  core            [{}]: DataStax Java driver 3.6.0 for Apache Cassandra
2020-01-22T10:48:29.922Z INFO  Native          [{}]: Could not load JNR C Library, native system calls through this library will not be available (set this logger level to DEBUG to see the full stack trace).
2020-01-22T10:48:29.922Z INFO  ClockFactory    [{}]: Using java.lang.System clock to generate timestamps.
2020-01-22T10:48:30.093Z INFO  NettyUtil       [{}]: Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
2020-01-22T10:48:32.048Z INFO  DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy [{}]: Using data-center name 'Cassandra' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
2020-01-22T10:48:32.052Z INFO  Cluster         [{}]: New Cassandra host VMAKSA69901DV0/10.137.228.55:9042 added
2020-01-22T10:48:32.053Z INFO  Cluster         [{}]: New Cassandra host /10.126.240.191:9042 added
2020-01-22T10:48:32.927Z INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [{}]: Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-01-22T10:48:33.575Z INFO  EndpointLinksResolver [{}]: Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path ''
2020-01-22T10:48:33.780Z INFO  RoutesCollector [{}]: Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
2020-01-22T10:48:33.781Z INFO  RoutesCollector [{}]: Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
2020-01-22T10:48:33.789Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Apache Camel 2.23.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2020-01-22T10:48:33.794Z INFO  ManagedManagementStrategy [{}]: JMX is enabled
2020-01-22T10:48:34.282Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2020-01-22T10:48:34.815Z INFO  JacksonDataFormat [{}]: Found single ObjectMapper in Registry to use: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@664db2ca
2020-01-22T10:48:34.925Z INFO  JacksonDataFormat [{}]: Found single ObjectMapper in Registry to use: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@664db2ca
2020-01-22T10:48:34.955Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Route: cli-lpidhash-accs started and consuming from: direct://cli-lpidhash-accs
2020-01-22T10:48:34.957Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Route: cli-total-lpidhash-accs started and consuming from: direct://cli-total-lpidhash-accs
2020-01-22T10:48:34.958Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2020-01-22T10:48:34.960Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Apache Camel 2.23.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.175 seconds
2020-01-22T10:48:34.979Z INFO  Http11NioProtocol [{}]: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9084"]
2020-01-22T10:48:35.027Z INFO  TomcatWebServer [{}]: Tomcat started on port(s): 9084 (http) with context path '/system-api/accountbylpidhash'
2020-01-22T10:48:35.036Z INFO  SystemapiCassandraAccountByLpidhashApplication [{}]: Started SystemapiCassandraAccountByLpidhashApplication in 10.492 seconds (JVM running for 13.435)
```

**The CommandLineRunner App log:**

```
2020-01-22T10:49:40.378Z INFO  RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedApplication [{}]: Starting RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedApplication on WV-MN14GLAE62KT with PID 23480 (started by c052699 in C:\Project Backups\InitialWorkspaces\rt-poll-msd-credit-cassandra-acctbyacctencoded)
2020-01-22T10:49:40.409Z INFO  RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedApplication [{}]: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-22T10:49:43.068Z INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [{}]: Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8b1c963] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-22T10:49:43.089Z INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker [{}]: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6880344] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-22T10:49:43.242Z WARN  DefaultBatchConfigurer [{}]: No datasource was provided...using a Map based JobRepository
2020-01-22T10:49:43.242Z WARN  DefaultBatchConfigurer [{}]: No transaction manager was provided, using a ResourcelessTransactionManager
2020-01-22T10:49:43.287Z INFO  SimpleJobLauncher [{}]: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2020-01-22T10:49:43.700Z INFO  GuavaCompatibility [{}]: Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
2020-01-22T10:49:43.721Z INFO  core            [{}]: DataStax Java driver 3.6.0 for Apache Cassandra
2020-01-22T10:49:44.010Z INFO  Native          [{}]: Could not load JNR C Library, native system calls through this library will not be available (set this logger level to DEBUG to see the full stack trace).
2020-01-22T10:49:44.011Z INFO  ClockFactory    [{}]: Using java.lang.System clock to generate timestamps.
2020-01-22T10:49:44.216Z INFO  NettyUtil       [{}]: Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
2020-01-22T10:49:46.239Z INFO  DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy [{}]: Using data-center name 'Cassandra' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
2020-01-22T10:49:46.242Z INFO  Cluster         [{}]: New Cassandra host VMAKSA69901DV0/10.137.228.55:9042 added
2020-01-22T10:49:46.243Z INFO  Cluster         [{}]: New Cassandra host /10.126.240.191:9042 added
2020-01-22T10:49:47.088Z INFO  DefaultTypeConverter [{}]: Type converters loaded (core: 195, classpath: 11)
2020-01-22T10:49:48.168Z INFO  RoutesCollector [{}]: Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
2020-01-22T10:49:48.170Z INFO  RoutesCollector [{}]: Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
2020-01-22T10:49:48.191Z INFO  RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedApplication [{}]: Started RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedApplication in 8.594 seconds (JVM running for 11.422)
2020-01-22T10:49:48.273Z INFO  SimpleJobLauncher [{}]: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=rtPollMsdCreditJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=1579670388197}]
2020-01-22T10:49:48.299Z INFO  SimpleStepHandler [{}]: Executing step: [rtPollNStoreStep]
```

I tried initializing the CamelContext and ProducerTemplate in the place where I am using it (i.e. in the DAO class as well tried initializing it in the main SpringBoot App and tried autowiring it in the DAO class) :

```
@Bean
public CamelContext camelContext() {
    return new DefaultCamelContext();
}

@Bean
public ProducerTemplate producer() throws Exception {
    return camelContext().createProducerTemplate();
}
```

(in the Web App I simply auto-wired it)

No luck so far.

**[Update]**
I got the camel context initialized like this:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

@Bean
public CamelContext camelContext() {
    return new SpringCamelContext(context);
}
```

The routes are also started:

```
2020-01-22T12:35:25.242Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Route: rt-poll-msd-credit started and consuming from: direct://rt-pollmsd-credit
2020-01-22T12:35:25.243Z INFO  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
```

Now, the issue(warnings) I am getting is :

```
2020-01-22T12:35:25.448Z INFO  RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedDao [{}]: query for insertAccountByLpidHash (insert in AccountByLpidhash): BEGIN BATCH insert into account_by_lpidhash(cust_lpid_hash,acct_nbr,prdt_cd,update_timestamp) values ('batchtestmklpo','123123','ccd','Wed Jan 22 12:35:25 IST 2020');insert into account_by_lpidhash(cust_lpid_hash,acct_nbr,prdt_cd,update_timestamp) values ('batchtestmklpo','31231','ccd','Wed Jan 22 12:35:25 IST 2020'); APPLY BATCH;
2020-01-22T12:35:25.449Z WARN  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Cannot find the class loader from application context, using the thread context class loader instead
2020-01-22T12:35:25.458Z WARN  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Cannot find the class loader from application context, using the thread context class loader instead
2020-01-22T12:35:25.460Z WARN  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Cannot use SpringInjector as applicationContext is not a ConfigurableApplicationContext as its: null
2020-01-22T12:35:25.478Z INFO  DefaultTypeConverter [{}]: Type converters loaded (core: 195, classpath: 11)
2020-01-22T12:36:00.058Z WARN  SpringCamelContext [{}]: Cannot use SpringInjector as applicationContext is not a ConfigurableApplicationContext as its: null
```

And I am getting an exception in the responseExchange1 object:

> exceptionDetail : No consumers available on endpoint:
>   direct://rt-pollmsd-credit.
>   Exchange[ID-WV-MN14GLAE62KT-1579679475416-2-1]

**Code:**

```
Exchange insertExchange1 = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext()).withHeader(CassandraConstants.CQL_QUERY, cqlInsertQueryAccountByLpidhash.toString()).build();
Exchange responseExchange1 = producer().send(ApplicationConstants.URI_RT_POLL_MSD_CREDIT, insertExchange1);
String responseBody1 = responseExchange1.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

Comment: What are the annotations you have in the class which implements CommandLineRunner?

Comment: @prakashb i have updated my question.
and as for your question:

#SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
#EnableBatchProcessing
public class RtPollMsdCreditCassandraAcctbyacctencodedApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

 #Autowired
 JobLauncher jobLauncher;

 #Autowired
 Job job;

// # = at_the_rate